# VS Code asp.net core debug fail

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create simple console app and debug it using vs code and c# extension. I have the following issue : 
When clicking debug button, error appears :

> launch: launch.json must be configured. Change 'program' to the path to the executable file that you would like to debug

launch.json path to executable looks like that :

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
```

this file is autogenerated by VS Code, so what's wrong???
moreover, replacing previous path by full file system path like

```
Alex/bin/Debug/aspnetcore/projectname.dll"
```

makes it work. Please, help me, i haven't found anything, i just want to click the "start debugging" button and debug without any problems.

Best wishes, Aleksey

Answer (score 4):

You can leave `${workspaceRoot}` in, the issue is with `<target-framework>` and `<project-name.dll>`

Here is an example that should work if you are running .NET Core 1.1:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/projectname.dll",
```

That will get the project to debug on any machine since it is a relative path unless you rename the project.  But the Visual Studio Code C# extension should not be auto generating a launch.json file that does not work.

I have opened a bug on this issue: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1126

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still hitting this issue:

1. Open up your `Program.cs` file **before** starting to debug in Visual Studio Code.

   - Opening any `.cs` file fires the C# extension.
2. The extension will then ask if it can load build assets. Hit Yes.

   - It may take a few seconds to load Omnisharp
   - It only asks this if the `launch.json` and `tasks.json` haven't already been added to the project.
3. Then the extension will configure your `launch.json` and `tasks.json` for you.

For those interested there is an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10861) tracking this behavior.